# Customize the SharePoint modern list forms using Power Apps while we have Nintex forms defined on the list

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, list-form, powerapp, nintex

Currently we have a SharePoint online site which contain a custom List. And this custom list have its list forms customized using Nintex forms. Now we need to convert the Nintex forms to be Power Apps. so can we achieve the following:-

1. Keep the user accessing the Nintex forms.
2. At the same time start customizing the SharePoint modern list forms using Power Apps.
3. once we are done with the Power Apps work, to remove the Nintex form and start using the Power Apps customized forms?

Not sure what i need to do to be able to start customizing the SharePoint modern list forms using Power Apps while our list uses Nintex? So end users will keep accessing the Nintex forms till we are done with the Power Apps work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can start customizing the form using the **PowerApps** also change the form in **Form Settings**

[image]

So that users will see the form that you have set